# Flutter: User-Defined Issue (Xcode): Unsupported Swift architecture

Tags: flutter, ios-simulator, huawei-analytics

I am trying to run my flutter app in ios via android studio, and i am encountering this error which i do not understand.

[image: User-Defined Issue (Xcode): Unsupported Swift architecture]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making these changes resolved my issue

[image]

Comment: Solved  cup for you

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue with the RevenuCat package. It turns out it was my fault all along. I had added the following code to my podfile a long time ago and forgot about it:

```
installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
    config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64"
end
```

Removing this fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

in my code I had this two lines in pod file which needed to be commented

```
config.build_settings["EXCLUDE_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = %w(arm64 i386)
config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=*]"] = "armv7"
```